# how to reauthenticate user in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

hi i need to reauthenticate my users to make the change of user's email and password in firebase. according to the documentation if I am using facebook login and google login I must reauthenticate to make the change.

```
 private void reauthenticate(){
        String MyEmail = emailText.getText().toString();

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(MyEmail, "Abc123");

        user.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");

                            updateEmailProfile();
                        } else {
                           Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");

                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

I need a form where I can capture the user's created password, with facebook, google, and email and password.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance (). GetCurrentUser ();
```

I can only get email name, but not password

Comment: you need to prompt the user with a screen asking for the password again

Comment: ok but in the case of google and facebook it is registered without a password. I can not ask for the new password

Comment: What your asking for doesn't make sense. If they are authenticated with a third party, their email / password is not necessary for your app. While you can retrieve their email (for marketing and such), they are being authenticated outside of your app; thus how are they "updating" an email/password? That should be something they change in facebook/google/etc, not in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Password isn't something that's supposed to be as easily accessible as an email, because by default a password is protected. If you want to reauthenticate the user then you need to have the user somehow re-enter the password associated with the user's account.